# C# Dynamic Linq Variable Where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I am following Scott Gu's article to create a dynamic LINQ 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

He has given an example:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> e1 = 
    DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<Customer, bool>("City = \"London\"");  
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> e2 =
    DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<Customer, bool>("Orders.Count >= 10");  
IQueryable<Customer> query =
    db.Customers.Where("@0(it) and @1(it)", e1, e2);
```

This works fine in my case. However I have unknown number of where clauses, which is decided at runtime.

Can anyone please tell me how to create a generic Where clause, such as

```
Where("@0(it) and @1(it) and... @n(it)", e1, e2, ... en);
```

Thanks

Comment: How about trying with something like db.Customers.Where( c => c.Order.Count > someVariable1 && c.Order.Count < someVariable2 );

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can attach additional operators on the `query` object:

```
 query = db.Customers.Where( ... );
 query = query.Where( ... );
 query = query.Where( ... );
```

This way you can attach clauses dynamically and you are independent on their count.

Comment: Thanks Thats what I am doing now

Comment: how to do IN clause in where?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a nuget package called `DynamicFilter.Sql` to achieve exactly this. For my requirement, I wanted to generate LINQ expression trees from sql syntax.

Here is how you would use it in your case.

```cs
var filter = FilterExpression.Compile<Customer>("City = 'London' and OrderCount >= 10");

//Filter a collection
var filteredCustomers = customers.Where(filter);
```

The package can generate code for complex logical/boolean operations and
support sql style filtering including `like`, `not like`, `in`, `not in`, `is null`, `is not null` etc.

The package is open source and available on [github](https://github.com/prakashrx/DynamicFilter.Sql), in case you would like to check the internals.