# c# How to evaluate compareTo(..) in Expression which returns a string

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

I have similar Situation like here: [How to declare a Linq Expression variable in order to have it processed as a dbParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188192/how-to-declare-a-linq-expression-variable-in-order-to-have-it-processed-as-a-dbp)

But in my case, don't want to compare with 'equal' operator, I need to compare one string against another. How can I achieve this?

I tried something like this:

```
    var comparsionString = "aaa";
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ItemSearch), "s");
    Expression prop = Expression.Property(param, "Id");
    Expression<Func<string>> idLambda = () => comparsionString;
    Expression searchExpr = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(prop, idLambda.Body);

    Expression<Func<ItemSearch, bool>> myLambda =
        Expression.Lambda<Func<ItemSearch, bool>>(searchExpr, param);
```

But unfortunately GreaterThanOrEqual is not supported for strings. So I would need the string.CompareTo(..) method which is supported at least by SQL to Entities.

Say:

```
Expression searchExpr = Expression.IsTrue(*prop*.CompareTo(*idLambda*) >= 0);
```

How to write this in a way, that compiler can understand?

Any help is apreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Can this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24890249/4222487

Comment: You can use LINQPad to output `Expression` variables that you initialize to something similar to your desired output and then write the code to re-create it. Nice use of `idLambda`, but an `Expression.Constant` might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you investigate the compiler translation for

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> f = s => s.CompareTo("aaaa") >= 0;
```

You will discover you need to use GreaterThanOrEqual(Call("s", "CompareTo", "aaaa")) so the code to create that is:

```
var comparsionString = "aaa";
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ItemSearch), "s");
Expression prop = Expression.Property(param, "Id");
Expression<Func<string>> idLambda = () => comparsionString;
var CallMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] { typeof(string) });
Expression callExpr = Expression.Call(prop, CallMethod, idLambda.Body);
Expression searchExpr = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(callExpr, Expression.Constant(0));

Expression<Func<ItemSearch, bool>> myLambda =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<ItemSearch, bool>>(searchExpr, param);
```

Comment: Genious! Works as a charm: Just one improvement: `nameof(string.CompareTo)` instead of "CompareTo" ;)

Comment: I'm not sure that is an improvement? The result of `nameof(String.CompareTo)` is going to be "CompareTo".

Comment: Well, don't call it improvement, it's just light weight cosmetica ;)

Comment: @user1470240 We all have our quirks when programming :)